# SQL Where exists case statement

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, case, where-clause, exists

I'm not sure how to combine a `if/case` with a `where exists` statement. All of the below fields live in `t_phone`

This is the set up - there is a phone temp variable that is declared

```
Declare @phone varchar(25)

`select @phone = ....`
```

What we need to say is for a given `customer_no` if `phone_type` (from `t_phone`) exists for that customer_no, with a type of 25 use the phone_no associated with type = 25, else use type 2.

so for example

```
phone_no          type           customer_no
1234567890          2                  4
0987654321          25                 4
6537327345          2                  8
```

based on the above example for customer 4 we want to set @phone = 0987654321, since there exists a type 25, but for customer number 8 we want to use type 2 since there is no alternative 25 type.

Comment: Do you have something that determines order of importance? Is it defined within a table or somewhere that is usable that 25 has priority over 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 2 and 25 are the only types, you could do a `SELECT MAX()` like below:

```
Select t.phone_no
from t_phone t
where t.type = (select max(ti.type) 
                from t_phone ti 
                where ti.customer_no=t.customer_no 
                and ti.type in (2,25))
```

Comment: Sadly they aren't the only values, but in this instance we want to look at only 2 and 25.

Comment: if you add that to your criteria, this should work. i have updated the answer

Comment: i'm getting this error message: `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Comment: I had to add another where clause in the first/main portion of the select and got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can make this easier to implement *and* maintain by introducing a table called `type_priority`. This will have two columns: `type` and `priority`. For `type=25`, `priority` will be highest say 10 and for `type=2` `priority` will be say 1.

Then, when you select join with this table, order by `priority DESC` and pick `top 1`.

```
select top 1 @phone = phone_no
from t_phone ph
join type_priority tp on tp.type = ph.type
where customer_no = @Customer
order by tp.priority desc
```

This data driven approach is more maintainable 'coz if you introduce other types, simply add rows to `type_priority` table with appropriate `priority` and the sql statement continues work the same.

Note that for `types` missing from `type_priority` table, records will not be selected. So, you need to make sure it is up-to-date with all newly introduced types.

Comment: I really like this idea, and have to do more research about implementing it - I have to get approval internally if we can add additional temp tables. Thank you for the info

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only dealing with a single customer and the only values you want are type 2 and 25 how about something simple like this.

```
select top 1 phone_no
from t_phone
where customer_no = @Customer
order by 
case type when 25 then 2
    when 2 then 1
    else 0 end
```

Comment: This is pulling an entirely different/wrong phone number. (expired one) I'm not sure why its doing this.

Comment: Oops...the order by should have a desc at the end. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @phone varchar(25)
select @phone = CASE t0.[type]
                WHEN 25 THEN t1.phone_no 
                WHEN 2 then t2.phone_no             
                else 0
                END
from tbl t0
left outer join tbl t1 on t1.type = 25 and t1.customer_no = t0.customer_no
left outer join tbl t2 on t2.type = 2 and t2.customer_no = t0.customer_no
```

Comment: This seems to be looking at the correct data element - but two things happen, one it takes a bit longer to run and as this code is part of a function called by many many procedures that may not be a great thing - but the bigger issue for the moment - I'm getting the error: `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '(414) 444-4444 ext.4444' to data type int.`

Comment: Make sure your variable or data type is not int because the characters (,),-,. are not integers but characters.

Comment: the t1 an t2.phone fields are varchars -  the customer_no's are integers but the remainder of the data are all varchars. i'm not even sure where its trying to convert the integer

Comment: Is "type" a varchar field? If so, that will be the problem because of the case statement and the on clause in the join section. You would have to change it to '25' and '2'.

Comment: type is an int, but it seems to be trying to convert the phone that it is returning back to a type int

Comment: Whoops, i know why. the else statement. Instead of 0, make it '0'

Comment: it worked, only for some reason this is running really long time - 31 seconds. wow. but the logic is there. thank you